# An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility'

Tags: angular, typescript

```
Require stack:
- /Users/Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-engine-host.js
- /Users//Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/schematic-command.js
- /Users//Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/add-impl.js
- /Users//Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
- /Users//Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
- /Users//Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
- /Users//Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
- /Users//Documents/event-application-workspace2/angularssr/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
See "/private/var/folders/gg/m_3qrs454xbdnxrqcky4r5xr0000gn/T/ng-2MGUGX/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

I am getting this error. angular 12.2.0. please help me.